# Adicionando a uma lista ela mesma. O que acontece?

Tags: python, lista

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = l1
l1.append(l2)
print(l1)
```

Por que esse algoritmo retorna uma lista de três pontos? O que essa nova lista significa?

Comment: este é o site do SO em português, traduza sua pergunta

Comment: Como você está criando uma referencia de l1 em l2, a l2 representa a l1. QUando você fez o append, você criou um "ponteiro" de l1 dentro de l1. Ou seja a quarta posição de l1 irá apontar para l1. È como se a quarta posição fosse a própria lista dentro dela.

Comment: Pra que a grosseria e sarcásmo, @Ricardo Pontual ? Isso aqui é SO, não Facebook. developeer4rt5-9, elabore melhor sua pergunta, para que possamos entender sua dúvida.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson Não houve grosseria/sarcasmo. A pergunta estava em inglês no [pt.so], a orientação para se traduzir a pergunta se fez necessária.

Comment: Entendi, estou do celular, não me atentei. Desconsidere meu comentário, peço desculpas.

Answer (score 2):

Como você está adicionando a lista nela mesma, isso criará uma recursividade. As reticências são exibidas justamente para que a exibição seja possível, caso contrário seria impossível definir qual seria a saída.

Considere a lista que você construiu após adicionar ela nela mesma:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, l1]
```

Se você fizesse `print(l1)` a saída seria, em tese, `[1, 2, 3, l1]`, mas o valor de `l1` dentro da lista também seria avaliado e, portanto, a saída seria:

```
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, l1]]
```

Poxa, mas o `l1` apareceu de novo e também seria avaliado para gerar a saída, produzindo:

```
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, l1]]]
```

E de novo...

```
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, l1]]]]
```

E de novo...

```
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, l1]]]]]
```

Isso não teria fim, então os desenvolvedores do Python optaram por exibir apenas uma reticência.

```
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
```

E uma lista que possui a ela mesma é uma lista cíclica. Parece fazer pouco sentido, mas é possível fazer isso porque internamente (lá em C) a lista do Python é implementada em uma estrutura de ponteiros para o tipo `PyObject`, que é o tipo que engloba todos os objetos no Python.

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    /* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
    PyObject **ob_item;

    /* ob_item contains space for 'allocated' elements.  The number
     * currently in use is ob_size.
     * Invariants:
     *     0 <= ob_size <= allocated
     *     len(list) == ob_size
     *     ob_item == NULL implies ob_size == allocated == 0
     * list.sort() temporarily sets allocated to -1 to detect mutations.
     *
     * Items must normally not be NULL, except during construction when
     * the list is not yet visible outside the function that builds it.
     */
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

Então quando você adiciona a lista nela mesma, você internamente está apenas adicionando um ponteiro do C, que referencia a própria lista, na lista. Quando você acessa o valor em `l1[3]` (nesse exemplo) basicamente você estará acessando o valor representado por esse ponteiro que aponta para a própria lista, retornando uma lista de 3 números e um ponteiro (que também apontará para ela mesma (recursivo)).

O fato de ser um ponteiro te permite fazer isso dado que o valor dele não precisa ser avaliado sempre que necessitar do valor da lista.

Você pode confirmar que são os mesmos objetos através do operador de identidade `is`.

```
assert l1 is l1[3]
assert l1 is l1[3][3]
assert l1 is l1[3][3][3]
assert l1 is l1[3][3][3][3]
assert l1 is l1[3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3]
```

Todas as verificações retornam `True`.